# Plotting using numpy and matplotlib with no display upon plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am trying to get a plot to show and I am able to produce the box for said graph with the x and y axis labeled as necessary, however the line/function in itself is not showing. Is there some sort of issue in my code that I am not noticing?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():

    X = []
    Y = []
    x = np.arange(-1.5,1.6, 0.101)
    X.append(x)

    for x in X:
        y = x**3 - x
        Y.append(y)

    X = list(X)
    Y = list(Y)

    print(X)
    print(Y)

    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.plot(X,Y)
    plt.show()

main()
```

Comment: Don't have a function named as main

Comment: fix your indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `X` and `Y` are lists *containing* arrays of points, where `plot` takes arrays of points.  If you really need `X` and `Y` to be lists containing arrays, then you need to call `plot` like `plt.plot(X[0], Y[0])`.  Typically, though, you would just have `X` and `Y` equal to arrays directly.